# cant boot directly into grub after ubuntu 18.04 install on pc with windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, windows-8

after installing ubuntu 18.04 on my hp laptop with windows 8, the system doesn't directly go into the grub after reboot, it always boot into windows.

The only way for me to access ubuntu is by going to the advance startup options on windows 8, and select the option to boot into ubuntu.

after selecting that option, it goes straight to grub.

How can I configure the machine to startup directly into the grub?

Comment: Open the UEFI settings, find the boot order section and select "Ubuntu" instead of "Windows bootloader".

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia the option for ubuntu doesn't show on the BIOS. It's odd because if I press F9 to see the boot options, there is an entry for ubuntu, is not the firts one, but it is listed, but if I press F10 and enter the BIOS to go to the boot order and lists the ubuntu option first, there is no ubuntu option, and I tried putting first all the options available to see which one will boot ubuntu but not one works.

Comment: Is it possible that you installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode?

Comment: And please [edit] the question and post brand/model.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I downloaded and executed boot-repair and it fixed the problem